# Criar client_secret manualmente em PHP para Laravel + OAUTH2

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth2

**Problema:**
Tenho uma aplicação com auto instalador. Quando o usuário configurar a sua conta, gostaria de cadastrá-lo manualmente na tabela `oauth_clients`, já com um secret só dele.

Se eu faço o procedimento manual pelo painel do *Laravel Passport* e uso as informações, obtenho meu token sem problemas.

Se faço o procedimento inserindo pelo banco de dados com um `client_secret` em *MD5*, simplesmente não funciona.

Algo me diz que o `client_secret` precisa ser criado exatamente de determinada forma.

Alguém sabe como?

**Detalhes:**
Rodando base de testes em *PHP 7.1*, *Laravel 5.5*.

Answer (score 0):

descobri pesquisando "na gringa":

```
$secret = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
```

UPDATE

Da forma acima não funcionou, mas da forma abaixo, sim:

```
$secret = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$password, 'secret', true));
```